# What is the use of (+) bareword with shift operator?

Tags: perl, shift

I'm learning the intermediate perl.In that now I'm studying about the  object references for class.In that they gave one package

```
{
    package Barn;

    sub new { bless [], shift }

    sub add { push @{ +shift }, shift }

    sub contents { @{ +shift } }

    sub DESTROY {
        my $self = shift;
        print "$self is being destroyed...\n";
        for ( $self->contents ) {
            print ' ', $_->name, " goes homeless.\n";
        }
    }
}
```

> in this I can't understand the work of plus sign with shift
>   operator. In text they said ,the plus sign is like bareword  it would
>   be interpreted as a soft reference: @{"shift"}

can you anybody clearly explain its work for using plus sign with shift operator?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without the plus sign, `@{shift}` is the same as the array `@shift` which doesn't call the `shift` operator at all. Adding the plus sign forces `shift` to be evaluated as an *expression*, so the `shift` operator is called

I would prefer to see `@{ shift() }`

Methods are normally written so that they extract the first parameter to `$self`, like this

```
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    bless [ ], $class;
}

sub add {
    my $self = shift;
    push @$self, shift;
}

sub contents {
    my $self = shift;
    return @$self;
}
```

Comment: So ,is the plus sign will prevent us from treat the shift operator as @shift array ?

Comment: @b.sabarathinamsaba: That's correct. It turns it into an expression instead of a string, so the `shift` operator is called and its return value is used

Comment: What would happen if you replaced the plus with a minus? For example: `perl -E 'sub t { push @{+shift}, 3} @a = 1..2; t(\@a); say join ",", @a'` gives `1,2,3`, whereas if you replace `+shift` with `-shift` you get `1,2`..

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I'm not sure that's a useful question. Monadic `+` is pretty much a no-op for scalar operands, but monadic `-` will do unintelligent things to references. (Try `perl -E 'say -[]'`.) While `-'xx'` is simply `-xx`. If you consider every operator as a separately-written function that may behave differently according to whether it is called in list, scalar, or void context then you would be about right. If the behavour isn't documented then experiment, but esoteric uses of operators like `@{+shift}` are ***very wrong*** in my book, precisely because they produce questions like this

Comment: @HåkonHægland: None of this is documented behaviour and so shouldn't be used. If you want to understand the internals of Perl then you should become familiar with the C source

Comment: @HåkonHægland: I can't discourage you enough from using whatever functionality you've found. The gems of the internals are all in the C source, meanwhile you should keep writing good, documented Perl solutions.

Comment: More accurately the `+` prevents `shift` from being a *bareword*.

Comment: @BradGilbert: I don't think that's more accurate than what I've written. A bareword is just an unquoted string

Comment: Yes, and adding a `+` causes the parser to treat it differently, and the rest of what you posted happens as a consequence. What you posted almost makes it seem as if it was bug or something.